# Why is Instant.now() sometimes formatted differently?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date

I have code that looks like this:

```
String PROPER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date d = sdf.parse(Instant.now().toString());
SimpleDateFormat properFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(PROPER_DATE_FORMAT);
String formatterDate = properFormat.format(d);
```

Now, most of the time, this code works but every now and then, I'll Instant.now() returning `2018-05-25T18:56:09Z` and then it will throw an exception bc the format doesn't match.

Why is it sometimes inconsistent?

The exception is `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-05-25T18:56:09Z"`

Normally, when `Instant.now().toString()` does return a String with the above format. Again, this code works most of the time but there are a few times when it doesn't and I'm puzzled as to why.

I thought about whether it was because there's a zero at the end but just wasn't displayed but I'm not convinced because I was able to get a value of 2018-05-25T20:06:58.900Z as a result of Instant.now().toString()

Comment: Thanks, I have included what the exception was

Comment: What's the value of PROPER_DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: I updated the question with the value.

Comment: perhaps sometimes the `Instance.now().toString()` call returns a value with only two digits in the ms (while the `format` expects three digits) ?

Comment: @bruno the exception is thrown before that line (while parsing) so the `PROPER_DATE_FORMAT` does not seem to be relevant in this case

Comment: No, whenever I print out the value of `Instant.now().toString()`, it returns a value with 3 digits, like this: 2018-05-25T20:06:58.905Z

Comment: I thought about whether it was bc there's a zero at the end but just wasn't displayed but I'm not convinced bc I was able to get a value of `2018-05-25T20:06:58.900Z` as a result of `Instant.now().toString()`

Comment: Why do you convert the instant to a string only to parse it into a date? Why not write `Date d = new Date(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());`

Comment: In this case, yes - but try parsing `2018-05-25T20:06:58.90Z` with the same formatter

Comment: Parsing `2018-05-25T20:06:58.90Z` with the same formatter will return the exception above as it should.

Comment: so, perhaps (once in a while) `Instance.now().toString()` returns only 1 or 2 digits in the ms (and not 3) as expected?

Comment: `Instant.toString()` outputs digits for millis only if necessary (if they are not `000`). So you have a one in thousand chance of hitting exactly the second (with all milliseconds digits zero) where your code will fail

Comment: Since you can use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, don’t use `Date` too, it’s long outdated and poorly designed. Only if you need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot change. Only in this case, use `Date.from(Instant)` for conversion. And under no circumstances *at all* use the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: To obtain your string in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you can use `LocalDate.now(yourZoneId).toString()`.

Comment: As an aside, on the Java 9 on my computer, `Instant.now().toString()` yields something like `2018-05-26T05:56:50.294304Z`, which your code converts to a `Date` of Sat May 26 08:01:44 CEST 2018. CEST is at offset +02:00, so you notice the time is not correct.

Answer (score 8):

When the nanoseconds is zero, it's not included in the formatted string. So the output would be formatted as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"

You can see the difference with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("Now:\t" +  now);

        final Instant zeroedNow = now.with(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0);
        System.out.println("Zeroed:\t" + zeroedNow);
}
```

The output looks like

```
Now:    2018-05-25T20:23:54.208Z
Zeroed: 2018-05-25T20:23:54Z
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code fails because [Instant.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) is documented as

> The format used is the same as DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.

And according to [DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

> The nano-of-second outputs zero, three, six or nine digits digits as necessary

So you have a one in thousand chance of getting an Instant where the millis are `000` and your code fails.

---

Anyway, your code is unnecessarly complex and could be replaced with

```
String formattedDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .format(Instant.now());
```

There is no need to transform the `Instant` into a String only to parse it into a Date and then transform it into a String again.

Comment: That is not what was asked.

Comment: I agree with @bruno — while yours is (probably) a better way to go about doing this conversion, it doesn't answer the question of _"Why is Instant.now() sometimes formatted differently?"_

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: "**Instant.now() sometimes formatted differently?**". Lets take a look at how Instance.now().toString() was implemented:

**Instant.now().toString() source**:

```
public String toString() {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(this);
}
```

Javadoc of

> DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT

> ```
>  When formatting, the second-of-minute is always output.
>  The nano-of-second outputs zero, three, six or nine digits digits as necessary.
> ```

**From this javadoc, we understand that Instance.now.toString() NOT always 24 length**.

If milliseconds is 000 -> It will produce the format like you got:

> 2018-05-25T18:56:09Z  - 20 length

NOT

> 2018-05-25T18:56:09.000Z - 24 length

Is everything clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can format Instant using

```
instant.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
```

if you want to use the same api and in absence of any standard approach you can think of putting following logic

```
Instant inst = Instant.now()
if(inst.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND) == 0)
inst  = inst.minusMillis(1)
```